# Server side sort/filter for normalized data

Tags: java, sorting, database-design, backend

My question is what would be the best design of table structure, code and UI server side processing.

As per my understanding, if I choose client side processsing, data should be less, may be a few thousand records, thats fine.

But when data is huge, we need to do server side processing, and then problem arises, most of the data we should keep in normalized form for for better storage structure but UI needs denormalized form for better filter and sort.
If I keep data normalized, I can change values but then for read, I need joins and sort/filter on those joins.

What is the best way to keep data to support server side processing.
Would like to consider scenarios where we have a table code_table( code, value) and for each data record in another table data_table, after some edit, we associate it with such code from code_table.

Now we need to show code values on UI and sort/filter on it. and we have 10–15 such tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are few things I would like to suggest, may be they will help you make a decision:

- **Joins**: Usually having a few joins to get your end results is not such a big deal, as long as number of rows are running into millions. You can optimise them by having the right indexes. Unless, there are specific reasons you don't absolutely want to use joins, I strongly prefer you go with a Normalised structure and joins. This will give you utmost flexibility. Do some benchmarking to see how far you can scale.
- **De-Normalization**: This should be an option if you think your Join queries cannot scale with the load you have. Having de normalized data will mean you can have Insert/Update/Delete inconsistencies. But this does not mean it cannot (or should not) be done. You will have to take some extra efforts in your server side code to ensure these inconsistencies do not creep in, but other than that you should be fine.

Comment: Hello Mustafa, I agree to your comments however, I wanted to know if these are the only ways and the best ways, or there are some better ways to do it as I mentioned there are 10-15 tables. In de-nom form, if I provide feature to update or insert then should it be updating in same tables or there should be a syncing process to sync my normalized tables to de-nom form.

Comment: IMO, SQL based DBs provide the most flexibility, and hence you should go with a normalised design unless you can prove it is not going to scale. SQL DBs have been around for a long time, and are very mature. They can provide you a lot of features that you need (or will need in the future).  If you do go with a denom form, you can update in place, no need of syncing IMO.